# Press a button on apple watch to call a function in parent app

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I have never tried creating an app with the watchKit extension and I am running into some problems. All I am trying to do is hit a button on the apple watch and then it will call a function within the parent iOS app. Here is what I have tried so far:

watch:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressedWK {

    [InterfaceController openParentApplication:@{ @"command": @"foo" }
                                     reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {

                                     }];
}
```

Phone app:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
  //Code to call function
  [self thisFunc];
}
```

Am I missing something or is there another way I should go about this?